Angular Material 15 - trigger event when table row loses focus
Given the angular material v15 table below, it appears that the (blur) event isn't supported.  What are other options for achieving the same?  I would like to execute a method when a row loses focus, either by clicking another row or clicking anywhere outside of the table itself?
Any suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Weight Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Symbol Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row (blur)="saveData(row)" *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>

